# POSTGRESQL- Query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm new to postgres and to programming and I already searched for solution for this but I couldn't quite get it. I'm trying to make a function that will return information about all the customers on that particular country whenever I call the country. This is the error that pops up. I'm really sorry for asking this but I've been stuck here since yesterday.

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
>   HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function country(text) line 5 at SQL statement

Here is the function:

```
create or replace function country(text) returns text as $$
begin


  select customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name 

  from customer 

  inner join address on customer.address_id = address.address_id 
  inner join city on address.city_id = city.city_id 
  inner join country on city.country_id = country.country_id 

  where country = '$1';
  end;
  $$

  language plpgsql;
```

Comment: You are querying, but not returning anything from the proc. How about using `language sql` as shown in the examples here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html

Comment: i changed it to sql and this pops up ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 5: select customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name 
        ^
im really confused

Comment: Look carefully at the examples. 35.4.4 has examples that match your scenario. You can try running them first, then changing to what you want. Notice the `language sql` version in the example does not have `begin` or `end` and has `out` parameters.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are executing a select statement in a PL/pgSQL function, then you should place the result of the query in some variable(s) (= the destination). Then you work with the variable(s) in the function. You should also have a `RETURN` statement.

```
create or replace function country(text) returns text as $$
declare                   -- declare some variables
  id integer;
  fname text;
  lname text;
begin
  select customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name 
    into id, fname, lname -- store query results in variables
  from customer 
  inner join address on customer.address_id = address.address_id 
  inner join city on address.city_id = city.city_id 
  inner join country on city.country_id = country.country_id 
  where country = $1;     -- don't quote parameter references

  -- do something with the variables and return a value from the function
  return format('%s: %s %s', id, upper(lname), fname);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Do note that the above only works if the query returns a single row. If the query returns multiple rows you can [use a loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) in the function. Even simpler, you can just return the results from the query like so:

```
create or replace function country(text)
returns table (id integer, first_name varchar, last_name varchar) as $$
begin
  return query
    select customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name 
    from customer 
    inner join address on customer.address_id = address.address_id 
    inner join city on address.city_id = city.city_id 
    inner join country on city.country_id = country.country_id 
    where country = $1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

But like [Evan Carroll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41276296/3304426) said, unless you need a PL/pgSQL function to modify the data before returning it, you are better off with a simple view.

Comment: How to deal it in `stored procedure` ?

Answer (score 1):

There might be some situations where we want to call another psql function from a function. If we just want to invoke the function and don't assign the return value to anything, then using `select inner_function_call();` inside the main function will throw this error. As the hint suggests, use `perform inner_function_call()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIOn func_process_client_contact(p_client_version_id bigint, p_publish_id bigint)
    RETURNS TABLE(status_message character varying)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare 
    p_rowcount int;
    BEGIN
        -- validating input parameters : start
        IF ( p_client_version_id IS NULL OR p_publish_id IS NULL )
        THEN 
            RETURN;
        END IF;
        -- validating input parameters : end 

       WITH cte_target AS
       (
            SELECT  
            g.name AS clientname,
            gcr.group_id AS clientid,
            cr.id AS clientrelationid,
            crc.id AS clientrelationcontactid,
            crd.id AS clientrelationdesignation_id
            FROM GROUPS g
            JOIN group_client_relation gcr ON gcr.group_id =g.id
            JOIN client_relation cr ON cr.id = gcr.client_relation_id 
            JOIN client_relation_contact crc ON crc.client_relation_id =cr.id 
            JOIN client_relation_designation crd ON cr.client_relation_designation_id =crd.id
        )
        SELECT * FROM cte_target ct WHERE ct.clientname='ABC';
        GET DIAGNOSTICS p_rowcount = ROW_COUNT;
        RAISE NOTICE 'returned % rows', p_rowcount;
        IF ( p_rowcount=0 )
        THEN 
           RETURN query SELECT 'hello' AS status_message;
        ELSE
            RETURN query SELECT 'Success' AS status_message;
        END IF; 
    END
$function$
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please use below to get result of given function..

```
create or replace function country(in_parameter text,out out_res refcursor) as $$
begin
open out_res for
select customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name 

from customer 

inner join address on customer.address_id = address.address_id 
inner join city on address.city_id = city.city_id 
inner join country on city.country_id = country.country_id 

where country = '$1';
end;
$$

language plpgsql;
```

Comment: hello Riya i tried it and it returned this result can you please help me?

Comment: country       
--------------------
 <unnamed portal 1>

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal for SQL. Normally, this would be a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html).

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
    SELECT customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name 
    FROM customer 
    INNER JOIN address USING (address_id)
    INNER JOIN city USING (city_id)
    INNER JOIN country USING (country_id);
```

Then you do

```
 SELECT * FROM myView WHERE country = ?
```

All of that said, if you insist on making this a function, and you shouldn't, you should make it a [`LANAGUAGE SQL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) and not `LANGUAGE plppsql`.

Comment: Can you please explain the impact of using `sql' in language rather than `plppsql`?

Comment: It's faster generally speaking. And only SQL can be inlined. It's also less complex and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for my colleague when she used ***OPEN MYCURS*** before the select query and ***RETURN MYCURS*** after the select query.